# Do these special kind of permutations have a common name?

Tags: permutations, terminology

Let $\pi:[n]\to [n]$ be a permutation, $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

We define $\pi(X) = \{\pi(i)|i\in X \}$ for $X\subseteq [n]$.
For $\mathcal{X}$ a family of subsets of $[n]$, $\pi(\mathcal{X}) = \{\pi(X)|X\in\mathcal{X}\}$.

For example, say $\mathcal{X} = \{\{1,2\},\{3\}\}$, then $\pi(\mathcal{X}) = \{ \{\pi(1),\pi(2)\}, \{\pi(3)\}\}$.

A permutation is called $\mathcal{X}$-preserving if $\pi(\mathcal{X}) = \mathcal{X}$.

Are there special names for $\mathcal{X}$-preserving permutations if

1. $\mathcal{X}$ is a partition of $[n]$ and all sets in $\mathcal{X}$ have the same size?
2. $\mathcal{X}$ is a partition of $[n]$?
3. $\mathcal{X}$ is a laminar family of $[n]$?

$\mathcal{X}$ is a laminar family if for each pair of elements $X,Y\in \mathcal{X}$, we have either $X\subseteq Y$, $Y\subseteq X$ or $X\cap Y = \emptyset$.

Comment: In the case where $\mathcal{X}$ is a partition of $[n]$, the $\mathcal{X}$-preserving permutations are just a direct product of the permutation groups on the individual parts of the partitions.

Comment: I believe the laminar case breaks down in similar fashion — if $X\subset Y$, then $\pi(\{X,Y\}) = \pi(\{X, Y\setminus X\})$ and the latter is a partition of $Y$.

Comment: I'm a little rusty with group theory. Say for the following example where $\mathcal{X} = \{\{1\},\{2\}\}$, each permutation groups consists of only the identity, so the direct product is also just the identity.  However, the permutation $\pi=(1 2)$ also works here.

Comment: Ahh! You're right, I hadn't considered that possibility. I believe that in that case, what you have is a [wreath product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product) $S_m ≀ S_n$, where $m$ is the size of the individual parts of the partition and $n$ is the number of parts of that size.

Comment: In the general case where $X$ can have parts of different sizes, you have a direct product of wreath products.

Comment: Related but maybe not exactly what you're looking for:  an *imprimitive permutation group* is a group of permutations such that the entire group preserves some nontrivial partition $\mathcal X$.